# Image is not showing in Angular Project

Tags: html, angular, image, amazon-s3

I originally had images stored in the "assets" folder of my Angular project, and they displayed successfully. However, due to the large size of some images, I moved them to AWS S3. While testing on various devices, I confirmed that the images appear as expected. However, some users are unable to view the images.

```
            <div [ngClass]="{ 'cursor-pointer': admin }" *ngFor="let singleImage of sponsorImages; let i = index;" 
                 class="box-outer d-inline-block mx-2" (click)="admin == 1 && selectImage(singleImage, i)">
              <img [src]="watchImagePath + singleImage.image" class="height-img" style="height: 50px;" (error)="handleImageError($event)" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Bucket CORS Policy:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 9000
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy166479883123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1664798831523",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "ARNName/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1695751247334",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "ARNName/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "HttpsOnly",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "ARNName*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have the Bucket policy of your S3 bucket?

Comment: can you check the error for the image in Network tab (Chrome debugger) in the browser? Answer is dependent on the error.

Comment: @Wandrille Yes, I added the bucket policy and bucket is public.

Comment: @AnandaNaphade There is no error coming. I tested many machine and the images are coming proper. but my client is not getting the images.

Comment: @Wandrille I added Bucket Policy.

Comment: Can you get the path of the image from inspect element and opening in a new tab ?

Comment: @DarshanUnadkat It is opening.

Comment: I don't see anything suspect in your bucket policy, sorry.